# How can I wait all XHR request to be loaded?

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer, ui-automation, playwright

I have a method for our website's search field.When I type a word into search field, server gives me a response.These responses sometimes can be a log so I have to wait for all XHRs to be loaded not a specific response.Tried waitForLoadState seems not working.Tried below code but it only returned one response not other requests?

```
async searchTextWithWait(value: string) {
      await(await this.page.waitForSelector("//span[contains(@class,'search-input')]/input")).type(value,{delay:80})
      await this.page.waitForResponse(response => {
        return response.status() == 200
    });

  }
```

Comment: Maybe add the `response.url()` into your condition? Your current code just resolves whenever any 200 response is received, regardless of it came from the request you want to wait for or not. I don't see a [mcve] here so it's hard to provide an answer beyond that broad suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution can help you:

```
const selector = "//span[contains(@class,'search-input')]/input";
await this.page.locator(selector).waitFor();
await Promise.all([
  this.page.waitForLoadState('networkidle'), // wait until there are no network connections for at least 500 ms.
  this.page.locator(selector).type(value,{delay:80}),
]);
```